# dpkg and google-chrome don't get along with gnome

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, packaging, dpkg

Install fine. Works fine. Next day the logo and apps menu entry is gone. Doesn't seem to matter what I do. On installation, GDebi refused to install the package, and crashed instead, so I used dpkg -i.

As for the logo and apps menu entry, I suppose I'll just have to glue it in place. Sorry Firefox.

I install the latest version with dpkg, I use it for a while, it goes into the Internet tab fine. Then I shut down, and the next time I start up it's missing. The program runs fine from a terminal as google-chrome

So, my question is, where are the details of this stuff stored? Is it a single text file in /usr? Is it a bunch of stuff that's hard to edit by hand? And where is the logo likely to reside?

I know there's probably a GUI way to do this, but it will be more satisfying, and possibly less error-prone, if I simply override whatever's causing Ubuntu/GNOME to lose the icon and applications menu entry.

Comment: @ixtmixiix might I ask where you got the package from?

Comment: From the Google website several days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard the same complaints from several people who tried to use recent development builds of Google Chrome.  You probably should use a more stable version of it (or use the Chromium browser provided in the Ubuntu repositories, which is the open source version of Google Chrome).  Or otherwise you can wait until Google fixes this bug...

Comment: It randomly fixed itself. I assume Google updates the browser automatically. It just started working one day.

Comment: @ixtmixilix It does update automatically--if it's running.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try:

1. Uninstall google-chrome completely: `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome`
2. Check within your $HOME that there's nothing left (configuration is in `~/.config/google-chrome`)
3. Also check that the application shortcut that is gone using `find ~ -iname "*chrome*"` (it's a . Desktop file)
4. Then cross  your fingers and reinstall?

As I'm running chromium-browser and not google-chrome the names above might be different, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Usually I find "reinstall" direction not so helpful, but in this case I agree and the directions are very clear.  You may consider trying chromium-browser rather than google-chrome if you aren't attached to the google branding and such.  chromium-browser is the open-source core of google-chrome and I haven't had a problem with either the packages in the Ubuntu repository or the packages in the beta ppa.

Comment: yes Steven I'm running chromium-browser actually :) so my instructions may contain some naming difference, shouldn't be a problem though